# How can I perform via mutiny sequential calls of services?

Tags: java, mutiny

How can I perform via mutiny https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/2.1.0/ sequential calls of services?

I need something like this:
Call service A THEN call service B THEN call service c with data of service B THEN call service D.
Every service should be called only after completion of previous.

Answer (score 1):

You would do:

```java
Uni<T1> a = callA();
Uni<T2> b = callB();
Uni<T3> c = callC();

return a.chain(() -> b).chain(() -> c);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this exact syntax.